# Ctrl+leftclick doesn't work with bundle files on Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, bundle, netbeans-8

I noticed that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+leftclick doesn't work with bundle files but work only with controller files in a Netbeans Java EE project. I tried to delete cache as mentioned in a similar topic but the solution didn't work.

Comment: i'm not sure, if this is possible for a bundle files!!

Comment: What do you mean by the term "bundle files". Can you provide the link to the "similar topic"?